# Log to webconsole from extension

Tags: logging, firefox-addon

Is it possible to log to the Firefox's webconsole from a firefox extension?

I have been trying with console.log Application.console.log going with proper mozilla code through interfaces but All I seem to be able to do is to log to the old error console.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Web Console for which website? Extensions aren't bound to any particular website.

Comment: I wanted to log from my extension on any website...

Comment: Error Console is global, Web Console however shows only messages for a particular page. Sounds like you chose the wrong tool and are trying hard to make it work nevertheless.

Comment: True but it has the proper functionalities that I need so I've stuck with it - I'm posting a reply in a second.

Answer (score 1):

window.content.console.log() does the trick

Answer (score 0):

Switch Environment to Browser and run the following code from Scratchpad

`gBrowser.contentWindow.console.log("Hello world");`

The message will be logged only by the current page's web console.